# FFT only along 3rd dimension of 3d array?

Tags: python, 3d, fft

I have a 3 dimensional NumPy array and I want to take the fft only on the 3rd dimension. In Matlab it is

```
b = fft(a,[],3)
```

But I am not sure how to do it in Python. I tried

```
b = np.fft.fftn(a, axes = 2)
```

but its not correct syntex.

Comment: Try `np.fft.fft(a, axis=2)`.

Comment: _TypeError: _fftn_dispatcher() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'_

Comment: Look at the name of the function I'm suggesting you call: `fft`, not `fftn`. You want to do a (or rather many) 1D FFT, so call `fft`, the 1D function.

Comment: Ahh! got it, it worked